# IIS website works with localhost, but not using an IP address

Tags: c#, .net, angular, iis, active-directory

I have an Angular frontend with a .NET framework backend, which has the following `web.config` file (nothing else about authorization/authentication):

```
<location path="Tokens">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
      <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I am using AD login, which is the `Tokens` controller, the rest is secured by JWT tokens.

My current problem is, I wish to test the website with other computers in the domain using IIS and the website works if I use `localhost`, but as soon as I use my IP, errors start appearing.

My frontend configuration JSON:

```
{
  ...
  "apiAddress": "https://IP:50505/",
  ...
}
```

And the backend `web.config` also contains this:

```
<add key="WhitelistedServerUrls" value="https://IP:34622" />
```

So if the IP in the config files is `localhost`, then everything works as it should, but if I exchange that for my actual IP, then I get CORS errors as shown in the image below:
[image]

None of these errors appear if I use localhost. Below is the list of the things I've tried:

- CORS should be correctly set up in the code, but just to make sure, I also configured it in the `HTTP Response Headers` feature in IIS

  - this fixed CORS errors, but brought different errors, also signalr had an error that CORS origin is set up twice
- I also added the website `https://IP` to local intranet in settings

  - prior to this, I was getting a login popup, doing this fixed it
- my bindings for both frontend and backend are https with a self-signed certificate

  - browser notifies, that the certificate is not valid

My guess is that my IIS is not configured correctly, as the website works if I use `localhost` instead of an IP address.

Comment: On the backend side, do you add the real ip address to the cors config?  `builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", build =>
{
    build .WithOrigins("actual IP adress").AllowCredentials();
}));`

Comment: @B_Cbk this is my CORS config:
`var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(SystemConfiguration.GetValueFromConfigSection("Authorization", "WhitelistedServerUrls"), "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true};
config.EnableCors(cors);`
it reads the actual IP from the web.config file

Comment: Do you have this definition in the  _<system.webServer>_  tag in your web config file? Your Cors configuration looks correct. `<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>`

Comment: Are you sure you can read the ip address in the web.config file?

Comment: @B_Cbk I do not, it should work without that or no? Because I have CORS configured in code.

Comment: @B_Cbk I will try debugging later, but it should be able to yes, it reads localhost correctly, so it should read the IP aswell I think

Comment: Can you share the settings in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You enabled Windows authentication, so that when CORS preflight request (anonymous OPTION request) sent by the browser arrives on IIS, 401 is returned by IIS and triggers the errors you see.

You will have to use IIS CORS module to properly process such preflight requests,

https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module